# How do I pass a reference from one property to another in a Python class?

Tags: python

I have a class that has instances of other classes as its properties:

```
from ctypes import *

class C():
    A = propA()
    B = propB()

    def __init__(self):
        class c_struct(Structure):
            _fields_ = [('_A', c_int), ('_B', c_int)]

        self._c_struct = c_struct()
```

I need to somehow "connect" the `propA` and `propB` classes to the internal structure `_c_struct` created in `C` to eventually get the behavior like so:

```
c = C()

c.A.val = 12
c.B.val = 13

c._c_struct._A == c.A.val == 12
```

Where `C.A` is able to manipulate `C._c_struct._A`.  I've attempted to do something like this:

```
from ctypes import *

class propParent():
    def set_ref(self, ext_ref):
        self._val = ext_ref

    @property
    def val(self):
        return self._val

    @val.setter
    def val(self, val):
        self._val = val

class propA(propParent):
    # Further definitions here
    pass

class propB(propParent):
    # Further definitions here
    pass

class C():
    A = propA()
    B = propB()

    def __init__(self):
        class c_struct(Structure):
            _fields_ = [('_A', c_int), ('_B', c_int)]

        self._c_struct = c_struct()

        self.A.set_ref(self._c_struct._A)
        self.B.set_ref(self._c_struct._B)
```

But it appears that `self._c_struct._A` returns a Python integer object and not the reference to the `_A` internal c_int object of the structure. How do I connect a property to a sub property of another property in the same class?

Comment: Would it be feasible to create a class with a single field? That would naturally pass the class by reference.

Comment: I'm not sure if I follow?  My problem is coming from the fact that `self._c_struct._A` doesn't appear to be returning a reference when making the assignment.

Answer (score 1):

This'd seem like a fit for a [descriptor](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html), which the [field `c_struct._A` is also](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#structures-and-unions):

```
In [3]: c_struct._A
Out[3]: <Field type=c_int, ofs=0, size=4>

In [4]: c_struct._A.__get__
Out[4]: <method-wrapper '__get__' of _ctypes.CField object at 0x7f967303cf48>
```

which is why it returns an `int` when accessed through a `c_struct` instance instead of the field itself. Start by defining one suitable for your use case:

```
class prop:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'prop({!r})'.format(self.name)

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        if not instance:
            return self

        return getattr(instance._c_struct, '_{}'.format(self.name))

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        setattr(instance._c_struct, '_{}'.format(self.name), value)
```

or just

```
def prop(name):
    name = '_{}'.format(name)
    return property(
        lambda self: getattr(self._c_struct, name),
        lambda self, value: setattr(self._c_struct, name, value))
```

Then define your original class:

```
class C:

    A = prop('A')
    B = prop('B')

    def __init__(self):
        class c_struct(Structure):
            _fields_ = [('_A', c_int), ('_B', c_int)]

        self._c_struct = c_struct()
```

Test:

```
In [36]: c = C()

In [37]: c.A
Out[37]: 0

In [38]: c._c_struct._A
Out[38]: 0

In [39]: c.A = 12

In [40]: c._c_struct._A
Out[40]: 12
```

For extra credit and if you're using a recent enough version of Python you can use [`object.__set_name__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__set_name__) to remove the need to duplicate the name, without having to resort to a meta class:

```
class prop:

    def __init__(self, name=None):
        self.name = name

    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        if self.name is None:
            self.name = name

    ...
```

and then define C as:

```
class C:

    A = prop()
    B = prop()

    ...
```

Comment: is the `__set__` and `__get__` Python 3 specific?

Comment: No, they've been around.

Comment: Just to add to previous: you have to use [new-style classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54867/what-is-the-difference-between-old-style-and-new-style-classes-in-python) in Python 2 for descriptors to work properly.